# Good PHP Resourse to work with Blogger API?

Tags: php, api, blogger

Please suggest the good PHP Resource to deal with the Blogger API, I need to interact with the Adding new post, editing post, deleting post and Fetching posts.
I saw the Zend Framework doing this, but please suggest some lighter lib for this.

Comment: Define "best". "Best" is usually troubled with opinion. So community wiki?

Comment: Turned to good :) how can i turn it to community wiki?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know you mentioned you wanted something other than Zend, but I have used the Zend Gdata module for a couple of projects (mostly interacting with Google Calendar).  It's been pretty easy to use and can be used standalone, that is without the rest of the Zend Framework.

Comment: Actually i wanted other lib, rather than zend because, zend includes lot of code, and most of it is not needed to me... just need to interact with blogger. Thanks

Comment: Upvoting because this is important - you don't need the rest of Zend to use Zend's Gdata library, and it is about as lightweight as it can be.  Any sluggishness is because Google's API's return a LOT of data that isn't necessary for 90% of the users.  Seriously, I don't think there is a lighter library that will interact with Blogger on the level you want, unless you want to write one yourself.

Comment: You can remove a lot of the Zend Gdata stuff if you are just using the blogger part.